# Create jQuery infinite loop of items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to accomplish an infinite loop of items inside 1 main div.
The idea is to show part of the items, then slide the left one outside of the screen, whilst another is added from the right side of the screen.
The following function is working, but the animate method doesn't work, it just changing the css without animating it. 
[image]

Am I doing it wrong?

Also any better approach would be welcome. I tried to search jQuery solutions but they didn't work well for me so i wanted to create another one.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var items = jQuery('.companies-logos div');
var temp;
var item_width = 0;

if(items.length > 9) {
  items.slice(9).remove();
  setInterval(function(){
    jQuery('.companies-logos').append(items[9]);
    items[9].style.marginLeft = '0';
    item_width = items[0].offsetWidth + 12.5;
    jQuery(items[0]).animate({marginLeft: '-' + item_width + 'px'}, 2000);
    // items[0].style.marginLeft = '-' + item_width + 'px';
    temp = items[0];
    jQuery(items[0]).remove();
    items.splice(0, 1);
    items.push(temp);
    // jQuery(items[items.length-1]).css('transition', 'all 2500ms');
    }, 2500);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are doing wrong. Use Owl Carousel 2.

Comment: I didnt want my visitors downloading a whole plugin just for some moving logos. needed something small and compact :)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in achieving the wanted result from above:

```
$(function(){  
  setInterval(function(){  
    var item_width = $('.companies-logos ul li:first-child').width() + 25;
    $(".companies-logos ul li:first-child").animate({"margin-left": -item_width}, 1500, function(){  
      $(this).css("margin-left",25).appendTo(".companies-logos ul");  
    });  
  }, 2000);  
});
```